# sulotion to inform users of their favorite updated shops with one email

Tags: php, mysql

i'm not sure if this is a right place to ask this but i give it a try .

i'm writing a sort of social network for e-shops or shop network .

there is a table called followers and it show who follows which shop

table 1  :

followers

```
+-----------+---------------------+---------+---------+ 
| id        | shop_id             | user_id | date    |
+-----------+---------------------+---------+---------+
|  1        | 1                   |    23   |392185767| 
+-----------+---------------------+---------+---------+
|  2        | 1                   |    34   |392333337| 
+-----------+---------------------+---------+---------+
```

every time a shop posts a product i'll put it in the update table (if it's not already there) to keep track of updated shops

table 2 :

updates

```
+-----------+---------------------+----------+---------+ 
| id        | shop_id             |UPcounter | UPdate  |
+-----------+---------------------+----------+---------+
|   1       | 2                   |      1   |392185767| 
+-----------+---------------------+----------+---------+
|   2       | 1                   |      3   |392333337| 
+-----------+---------------------+----------+---------+
```

So here is the problem , i want to inform the followers of the update of their favorite shops via email .

easy way is to read the updated shops 1 line at the time , get their followers and send them an email (i use crone job to run this )

```
//select one updated shop
$uopdated_shop = $db->query("select updates.* , shops.* from updates  JOIN shops ON updates.shop_id = shops.id LIMIT 1");
if(!$uopdated_shos){ exit; }

// get it's followers
$followers = $db->query(" slsect f.* , u.* from followers f JOINE users u ON f.user_id = u.id
where f.shop_id = $uopdated_shop->id JOIN ");

$email->send($followers , $uopdated_shop , $sleep_betwwen_emails = 200 );
```

but this way one user may get up to 20-30 emails per day ... assuming he's following 20-30 shops !

i'm looking for a solution or algorithm to send each user , list of updated shops that he follows instead of one email for each updated shop .

one way is to loop through all users and get each one followed shops and look for them in the updated shops  , but with couple thousand users that may take days to complete .

Comment: combine the two queries so you get a list of `users - updated shops`? that or reverse the order. get a list of users first, then check for updated shops for that user.

Comment: @MarcB thanx but i can't send all those emails at once and users may get to couple thousands it wouldn't be a good idea to loop trough all oF them

Comment: but that's the whole point. you get a list of users, then check for EACH user what shops are new. you build a single email that lists those shops for a particular user, then send ONE email. your method is "ok, shop #1... which users are on this? spam them! next... shop #2. send more spam, etc...". Unless your queries take extremely long times to run, this would be far more efficient (1 email per user) rather than #updated shops * #users emails.

Comment: If don't want to loop through all updated shops, retrieve shops and users limited amount at the time. For example, you can do `do {} while( $shopsRetrievedAmount )` and, in this loop, retrieve 5 shops at the time and another such loop to retrieve 200 users at the time in it

Comment: @MarcB you make a good point  ,  thank  you .

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to concatenate the names of the shops together.  Something like:

```
select u.*, group_concat(s.shop_name)
from followers f JOIN
     users u
     ON f.user_id = u.id join
     updates up
     on up.user_id = f.user_id join
     shops s
     on up.shop_id = s.shop_id
where f.update > <whatever update time>
group by u.user_id
```